# Progress bar in WPF MVVM and TPL dataflow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm using TPL dataflow in a WPF application following the MVVM pattern.
I have a `TransformBlock<object,object>` and an `ActionBlock<object>` and I'm linking them like so:

```
transformBlock.LinkTo(notificationBlock);
```

The `ActionBlock<object>` should update the progress bar in my view with the current progress, but the UI seems to be frozen and only updates when everything finishes processing.

My `CurrentProgress` property looks like this:

```
private double _CurrentProgress;

public double CurrentProgress
{
    get { return _CurrentProgress; }
    set
    {
        _CurrentProgress = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
    }
}
```

and I'm binding it to my View like so:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" Name="uxProgressBar"/>
```

Am I missing something? why is TPL blocking the UI thread?

***EDIT***

This is how I'm instantiating the TPL:

```
foreach(var myObj in ObjList)
{
    transformBlock.Post(myObj);
}
```

Transform Block:

```
TransformBlock<object, object>(
temp =>
{
    var response = ProcessRecord(temp);
    return response.Status;
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism =20
});
```

Action Block:

```
ActionBlock<object>(
temp =>
{
    CurrentProgress = (double)temp.RecordNumber/(double)TotalRecords;
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
});
```

***UPDATE***

The web service being called in the `TransformBlock` was a legacy (asmx) web service and it wasn't being called `Async`. After fixing this issue everything else works fine without using the `Dispatcher` or any of the other suggested solutions.

From one of the comments to the question it seems like WPF does support posting to the UI Thread from another Thread. I haven't been able to find any official documentation about this though.

Comment: How are you instantiating the `TPL?`

Comment: Post relevant code, you are probably not 'awaiting' properly on your code.

Comment: I like to get things working in sample projects. I don't have a TPL example, but check out this project. Get TPL working in this sample project and then move to your production project. http://www.wpfsharp.com/2010/12/29/a-progress-bar-using-wpfs-progress-bar-control-backgroundworker-and-mvvm/

Comment: Are you `Wait()`ing for the `Completion` of the blocks, or something like that? How many items are there and how long does it take to process them?

Comment: @svick I'm fairly new to TPL dataflow. The code that I've posted is basically all of the code, there is nothing `Wait()` anywhere else.

Comment: @EliArbel I think you are right, the issue was somewhere else. The web service being called was a legacy web service (asmx) and it was being consumed synchronously as opposed to asynchronously and that's why the UI thread was being blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `ActionBlock` don't have to change the `CurrentProgress` property directly.

The reason is that the `RaisePropertyChanged` function will directly run code of the `ProgressBar` Object.
Which is not allowed as it's an Object owned by the UIThread.

The `ActionBlock` run in his own thread, and he need to post the progressBar update order to the UI Thread (by using the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`) :

```
ActionBlock<object>(
temp =>
{
    double progress = (double)temp.RecordNumber/(double)TotalRecords;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        CurrentProgress = progress;
    }));
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
});
```

You'll have to change this first thing for sure in order to make what you want.

Secondly (if this does not change anything), you have to check that your UI Thread is not waiting for the completion of your `TransformBlock`. If your `ICommand` (if you're calling it from a button for exemple) is not ASync and do something like this :

```
transformBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

It's not ok. Because your UIThread will wait for the end of your treatment and will not take the previous progressBar update orders until the end.

Good luck !
Please post new details if it's alway not working.

Comment: Wouldn't accessing CurrentProgress from a background thread throw an InvalidOperationException? he should have seen that, or maybe the ActionBlock is swallowing the exception?

Comment: As you said, it's swallowed. You only see it if you're debuging the application (with the Debug -> Exception -> catch exceptions checked), or if you're waiting for the ActionBlock.Completion. Wait().

Comment: Is this the common behavior for any TransformationBlock?

Comment: The Exception thrown will have an effect on your TPL network (at least it will kill your ActionBlock Thread), but your main Thread (in this case the UIThread) won't be notified directly, unless you create a dependance between him and your TPL Threads (by waiting for one of them for exemple).
If you are interested in this specific subject, you may find some useful information here : [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am aware of the TPL way of propagating exceptions,  was wondering if Dataflow behaves the same :)

Comment: As far as I know yes. A more experimented guy on this subject could enlighten us :) That would be interesting.

Comment: [Here you have simple samples on TPL Dataflow.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I've just run one of them without the try/catch block and it's confirmed, the main Thread is not aware of the exception.  On the ActionBlock side, The `.Completion.IsFaulted` become true and it doesn't process input anymore. That's all.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for that info, maybe you should add it to your response.

Answer (score 2):

Try posting your code to the TransformBlock using 'SendAsync':

```
foreach (var myObj in ObjList)
{
   await transformBlock.SendAsync(myObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Dispatcher` to notify the UI thread that you want to update a bound value from a background process.

Here is a link to an article explaining:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.threading.dispatcher

I will put together a similar code example and update this response shortly.